# Document is not saving in the stream

Tags: c#, file-io, html-agility-pack

I am using HtmlAgility pack. After loading and manipulating the html document i am trying to save it in the Stream but it is not saving :

```
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  HtmlDocument newdoc = new HtmlDocument();
  newdoc.load(Inputstream);

   .... manipulate the document ...
  newdoc.Save(ms);
```

It load the document from the stream perfectly but not save it.What i am doing wrong here ?

Comment: You're saving it to a null stream... Is this your actual code?

Comment: Please use the debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, look:

```
Stream outstream = Stream.Null;
...
newdoc.Save(outstream);
```

Where do you *expect* that to save?  You need to give it a stream which will actually write to somewhere you care about...

Comment: thanks but it will really helpful if you please elaborate , i am weak in File.IO

Comment: @KingKong: Well you haven't given us any indication of where you're *trying* to write it... You might want to use `File.OpenWrite` for example. Personally I would suggest you put down HtmlAgilityPack and learn about basic IO before going any further - it's important to work up from basics to more advanced topics.

Comment: I want to save the stream data in the cloud blob storage , something like `blobinstance.UploadFromStream(stream)`

Comment: @KingKong: Then you should probably write to a `MemoryStream` first (and rewind it) - but again, using cloud storage is a relatively advanced topic. *Please* learn from the ground up - it'll be much quicker in the long run.

Comment: but i tried that also `MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();` `newdoc.Save(ms);`

Comment: @KingKong: Right, and then you need to rewind it (set the Position property to 0) and then you can use `UploadFromStream`.